# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I have a problem with my metaslider on my wordpress site.
it works fine on my homepage, but on all the other pages i get the same error.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
metaslider_158 @ (index):210
timer_metaslider_158 @ (index):225

I tried all sliders like: R. Slides/ Nivo Slider/ Coin Slider
all the same error.

the code of the metaslider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var metaslider_158 = function($) {
            $('#metaslider_158').addClass('flexslider'); // theme/plugin conflict avoidance
            $('#metaslider_158').flexslider({ 
                slideshowSpeed:3000,
                animation:"fade",
                controlNav:false,
                directionNav:false,
                pauseOnHover:true,
                direction:"horizontal",
                reverse:false,
                animationSpeed:600,
                prevText:"&lt;",
                nextText:"&gt;",
                slideshow:false
            });
        };
        var timer_metaslider_158 = function() {
            var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_158, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_158, 1) : metaslider_158(window.jQuery);
        };
        timer_metaslider_158();
    </script>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: It probably means that you're not including the script on those pages.

Comment: Check in other page's header area to see whether required js called on the page header

Comment: wouldn't 'var metaslider_158 = function () {' solve the problem? so you aren't passing the $ object to your function.

Comment: i have 52 js in the header on the homepage and only eleven in the head in the other pages.... so i need te copy all of them?

Comment: unlockedluca i will try it in which document do i need to be? I'm not really a programmer... i know html css php and drupal and wordpress but not javascript

Comment: And does someone know why wordpress doesn't copy the js lines in the other pages?

Comment: I think i have the code : `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/website%20wijkraad/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/easing/jQuery.easing.min.js?ver=3.3.4.1"></script>` is this the one?

Comment: @Pointy  in which document do i need te be for the code?

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I used the minified version, the error was gone!